# How to extract email fields from headers with awk or grep

Tags: awk, grep, mbox

Regarding: mailbox (mbox format) email messages

**Multi Message File:** Inbox.mbox

```
From - Thu Mar 26 16:16:21 2015
From: Mail Delivery System <Mailer-Daemon@200.netwizz.com>
To: edge@notterribe.org
Subject: Mail delivery failed: returning message to sender
Message-Id: <E1Yb3yX-0004CB-QH@200.netwizz.com>
Date: Thu, 26 Mar 2015 02:21:17 -0700
Date: Thu, 26 Mar 2015 02:20:44 -0700
From: edge <edge@notterribe.org>
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Icedove/31.5.0
MIME-Version: 1.0
To: leasing@theedgehenderson.com
CC: etpmgr@movein.net, t.simmonds@movein.ne
Subject: Fwd: Today's Breach Of Our Security.
From - Fri Mar 27 12:00:00 2015
```

**Desired Pattern Match Order;**

```
Date: Thu, 26 Mar 2015 02:21:17 -0700  
From - Thu Mar 26 16:16:21 2015  
From: Mail Delivery System <Mailer-Daemon@200.netwizz.com>  
To: edge@notterribe.org  
Message-Id: &lt;E1Yb3yX-0004CB-QH@200.netwizz.com>  
Subject: Mail delivery failed: returning message to sender
```

**Desired Final Result;**

```
Date: Thu; 26 Mar 2015 02:21:17 -0700;From - Thu Mar 26 16:16:21 2015;From: Mail Delivery System <Mailer-Daemon@200.netwizz.com>;To: edge@notterribe.org;Message-Id: &lt;E1Yb3yX-0004CB-QH@200.netwizz.com>;Subject: Mail delivery failed: returning message to sender
```

**Objectives;**
* Each mail message in "Inbox.mbox" starts with "From "
* Match 1st occurance once only for "^Date: |^From |^From: |^To: |^Message-Id: |^Subject: ", print that line.
* Format Output results in csv seperated by semicolon

I've tried;
`grep -a -E -i "^Date: |^From |^From: |^To: |^Message-ID: |^Subject: " Inbox.mbox

awk '/^Date: / || /^From / || /^From: / || /^To: / || /^Message-ID: / || /^Subject: /' Inbox.mbox`

**Comments:** The above gave me a good start, I'm most familiar with awk and grep so I'm trying to use them only. Having difficulty printing out the lines in order I wish, matching the 1st occurance only ending in a newline. Binary data existed in some messages so I used -a with grep.

Any assistance would be most appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Getting closer with: $ `awk '/^From / { head=1; $1 = ""; from = $0 } /^From: / { head=1; $1 = ""; from2 = $0 } /^To: / { head=1; $1 = ""; to = $0 } /^Date:/ { head=1; $1 = ""; date = $0 } /^Subject:/ {head=1; $1 = ""; subject = $0 } /^Message-ID: / { head=1; $1 = ""; message = $0 } NF == 0 && head == 1 { head=0; print from"\t", from2"\t", to"\t", date"\t", subject"\t", message }' Inbox.mbox`

Comment: I suggest you to do it with another library than pure shell (like [Python](https://docs.python.org/2/library/rfc822.html)), [RFC5322](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5322) are especially tricky to parse, not even saying there are many different [mbox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mbox) formats.

Comment: Stuck with the shell. I'm pretty sure each record of the Mozilla Thunderbird mbox mail file starts with a "From " and ends with 2 blank lines. `awk '/^From /,/^"\n""\n"^From / {print $0}' Inbox.mbox`

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so you have only Thunderbird mbox.

Here is my idea, in a file named `mbox2csv`:

```
#!/usr/bin/gawk -f
BEGIN {
    # initialize an array and set the "i" variable to 0
    i = split("", row, ":");
}

# awk does not have a "join"
function join(array, sep) {
    sep = sep ? sep : ";";
    result = array[0];
    for (i=1; i<length(array); ++i) {
        result = result sep array[i];
    }
    return result;
}

# the keys you want to store
/^(From|Date|To|Message-ID|Subject):/ {
    row[i++] = $0;
}

# every time we match a mbox message separator
/^From /{
    # if there is data (not the first line)
    if (length(row) > 1) {
        print join(row);
        # reinitialise the array and "i"
        i = split("", row, ":");
    }
}
```

Then: `mbox2csv INBOX > result.csv`

**Big warning:***
This does not take in consideration line continuation which is common in internet headers, nor escaping rows.

**Edit:** the code will be on [gist](https://gist.github.com/romain-dartigues/376c0810d7b91be1728d)

Comment: thanks for the solution. Error messages... I have awk not gawk, can I change /usr/bin/gawk -f to /usr/bin/awk -f ?, cut and pasted your code to mbox2csv, chmod a+x mbox2csv. In terminal: $ ./mbox2csv Inbox.mbox > result.csv . Fail with Errors: `awk: ./mbox2csv: line 11: illegal reference to local array array<br/>
awk: ./mbox2csv: line 25: illegal reference to array row`

Comment: Which `awk` version? `nawk`? `bwkawk`? `mawk`?

Comment: I stand corrected, it's 'mawk' mawk 1.3.3 Nov 1996. Wow that's old. Is it recommended to use a more modern version of awk ? Thanks. $ locate awk | grep /bin ... shows /usr/bin/awk
/usr/bin/gawk - Confusing.
/usr/bin/igawk 
/usr/bin/mawk 
/usr/bin/nawk

Comment: Timed out on comments editing. $ dpkg -i "*awk*" shows the only version on the system is:  mawk    1.3.3-17    amd64

Comment: I'm unable to find a `mawk` release prior 2010-12-10b; you could test the [code from the gist](https://gist.github.com/romain-dartigues/376c0810d7b91be1728d) but i doubt it'll work on such an old release. You could try to compile a recent version or find a standalone build of an awk interpreter.